# How can I restrict a column to certain values from another table without using a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

This is for SQL Server 2008.

I have a master lookup table that looks like this:

```
Mstr_lookup_ID  *Lookup_ID*   *Lookup_Category*   Lookup_Value
      1              1            States            CA
      2              2            States            NY
      3              1            Airlines          SWA
      4              2            Airlines          United
      5              3            Airlines          American
```

I have my primary key on `Lookup_ID` and `Lookup_Category`. I have a table that where I would like to restrict values in certain columns based upon the combination of `Lookup_ID` and `Lookup_Category`.

```
Create Table Main_Table 
(State_id    INT      --ONLY VALUES ALLOWED SHOULD BE 1-2
 Airline_id  INT)     --ONLY VALUES ALLOWED SHOULD BE 1-3
```

Is there a way to accomplish this neatly?  I'd like to create a foreign key for it, but my primary key is on two columns. I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) - it's point #1. It *sounds* like a great idea at first - but it's really not, precisely because it defeats the **main purpose** of a lookup table - being able to **enforce referential integrity**. Don't do this - use a separate lookup table for each category and use proper referential integrity!

Comment: marc_s, you should have made that a formal Answer.

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, I think "don't do this because of the issues you're already starting to encounter" should be an acceptable answer here.

Comment: You've tried to make this *look* like a category-relation, but it really isn't.  It's really the classic Master Code Table mistake.

Answer (score 1):

See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/).

What you're trying to do is their point #1.

It *sounds* like a great idea - at first. Having just one table instead of many ...

But it's really not, precisely because it defeats the main purpose of a lookup tables - being able to **enforce referential integrity**.

Don't do this - use a separate lookup table for each category and use **proper referential integrity**!

The only way you could make this work would be to have a `INT IDENTITY` on this "global" lookup table - but that ID would be "global" across all categories. Then you could reference this global lookup table based just on that one ID. The downside is that your categories won't all have nice consecutive numbers - it'll be all over the place.

Comment: I love how it's #1 on the article.  I tried to have separate lookup tables and was overruled.  I might try again, or I'll have to drop the 2nd column, and just make the 1st column the primary key and use that, which I was kind of trying to avoid.

Thank you all for your prompt and well thought out responses.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a "one big lookup table"?

To create a FK (and there is no other declarative way to restrict values based on lookup table, otherwise you can use triggers) you have to add another column to the `main_table` ie the `lookup_category` column, and draw the reference using both columns to the primary key in the lookup table.